# Command line difftool, git integration, side by side

Tags: command-line, git, diff

`git diff`, by default, shows changes one after the other and I find it hard to follow no matter how much practice I get.

I tried switching my git difftool to use `vimdiff` which gives me the side by side, but is too heavy-weight, I don't need it to be so interactive and sometimes I just want all the changes dumped to stdout.

I'm looking for a tool that:

- Is compatible with `git diff`
- Works at Unix **command line** (Mac OS and RHEL both required, Cygwin command like preferred but not required)

  - Not interested in a tool that uses a GUI like Beyond Compare (unless Beyond Compare has a CLI only mode that I am not aware of)
- Shows changes side by side
- Is not as heavy weight as `vimdiff`, i.e. just shows all the changes one after the other like the `git diff default`

Is there such a tool? Or perhaps can I tweak the options of either `git diff` or `vimdiff` to get what I want?

Comment: my `diff` takes a `-y` flag to do side-by-side. Perhaps you can get git to call `diff -y` if it is the same for you?